# Display items from list into a div

Tags: javascript, html

I have two div tags with lists inside.

Using Javascript I am trying to put each item from the "intoleranceList" into a string and then display it in the "info" div tag. 
Can anyone help? Here's my Javascript trying to do this.

```js
var area= document.getElementById("info");
var listArea = document.getElementById("intoleranceList").getElementsByTagName("li");
var intoleranceArray = [];
for(let i = 0; i < listArea.length; i++) {
   intoleranceArray[i] = listArea[i].innerHTML;
}
var intoleranceString = intoleranceArray.toString();
area.innerHTML = intoleranceString;
```

```html
<div id = "intoleranceList">
  <ul class = "list">
    <li>One</li>
    <li>Two</li>
    <li>Three</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div id = "nonIntoleranceList">
  <ul class = "list">
    <li>One</li>
    <li>Two</li>
    <li>Three</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div id = "info"></div>
```

Comment: Did you mean to use `listArea.toString()`, or should that be `intoleranceArray.toString()`?

Comment: @Jacob Oops you're right! Have it fixed now. It still isn't working though.

Comment: you need to insert only the text separate by comas in the <div id = "info"></div>
 or you need to insert the li tags inside it?

Comment: It's working for me, if the goal is to have a comma-separated list of items: https://jsfiddle.net/syw5rqu8/. Are you maybe running your JavaScript in a tag before the HTML in your page? If so, try moving your script to the bottom of your body.

Comment: @OscarVelandia The text separated by commas. So it would be "Three, Two, One".

Comment: @Jacob I moved it and it was working. Thanks for recommending that!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```js
const intolanceList = document.querySelectorAll("#intoleranceList > ul > li");//only select li's inside a ul tag and inside a intoleranceList id
const info = document.getElementById("info");
const text = [];

intolanceList.forEach(i => {
  text.push(i.textContent)//catch every text and push to array
})

info.textContent = text.join(" ")//catch array and transform in string with spaces between itens
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried to achieve this using Javascript ES5 :

```js
window.onload = function () {
  var intoleranceList = document.querySelectorAll('#intoleranceList li');
  var intoleranceListStrings = getStringListFromLi();

 AddStringsToInfo(intoleranceListStrings);

  function AddStringsToInfo(arr) {
    var infoElement = document.getElementById('info');
    infoElement.textContent = arr.join(',');
  }

  function getStringListFromLi(){
    var intoleranceListStrings = [];
    for(var i=0;i<intoleranceList.length;i++){
      intoleranceListStrings.push(intoleranceList[i].textContent);
    }
    return intoleranceListStrings;
 }
}
```

```html
<div id="intoleranceList">
  <ul class="list">
    <li>One</li>
    <li>Two</li>
    <li>Three</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div id="nonIntoleranceList">
  <ul class="list">
    <li>One</li>
    <li>Two</li>
    <li>Three</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div id="info"></div>
```

And using ES6

```js
window.onload =  () => {
  const intoleranceList = document.querySelectorAll('#intoleranceList li');

  const AddStringsToInfo = (arr) =>  {
    const infoElement = document.getElementById('info');
    infoElement.textContent = arr.join(',');
  }

  const getStringListFromLi = () => {
    const intoleranceListStrings = [];
    for(let i=0; i<intoleranceList.length ;i++){
      intoleranceListStrings.push(intoleranceList[i].textContent);
    }
    return intoleranceListStrings;
 }

  const intoleranceListStrings = getStringListFromLi();
 AddStringsToInfo(intoleranceListStrings);

  
}
```

```html
<div id="intoleranceList">
  <ul class="list">
    <li>One</li>
    <li>Two</li>
    <li>Three</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div id="nonIntoleranceList">
  <ul class="list">
    <li>One</li>
    <li>Two</li>
    <li>Three</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div id="info"></div>
```